# How to ensure my SQL varchar field is unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm sure this is really simple but I've been up through the night and am now getting stuck.

I have a piece of functionality that clones a record in a database however I need to ensure the new name field is unique in the database.

eg, the first record is

```
[ProjectName]   [ResourceCount]
'My Project'         8
```

Then when I click the clone I want

```
 'My Project Cloned', 8
```

But then if I hit the button again it should notice that the cloned name exists and rather spit out

```
'My Project Cloned 2', 8
```

Is that making sense?

I can do it with temp tables and cursors but there has to be a much nicer way to do this?

Using SQL Server 2008 R2

The solution needs to be entirely T-SQL based though, this occurs in a single stored procedure

Comment: Wait, what? Why? Why not just concatenate the date and time with the ProjectName then?

Comment: It is not our job to ask business why... it is just to do and die :).. Seriosuly though this is the business request so it's got to be done

Comment: Yes, you have to provide useful features to the business. No, you don't have to do this in exactly the way you're trying to. If there's an identity column on this table and rows are never deleted (or only soft deleted) there's no reason you cannot generate the correct numbering in a view or similar, during selection. You don't necessarily have to *store* this string. Even if you do want to store the number, it would be more sensible to store the number separately and make the *display* project name be a computed column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this using an IF EXISTS inside a WHILE loop..

Personally I can't see what's wrong with this method but will obviously take any comments into account

```
DECLARE @NameInvalid varchar(100)
DECLARE @DealName varchar(100)
DECLARE @Count int
SET @Count = 1
SET @NameInvalid = 'true'

SELECT @DealName = DealName FROM Deal WHERE DealId = @DealId

--Ensure we get a unique deal name
WHILE( @NameInvalid = 'true')
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT DealName FROM Deal where DealName = @DealName + ' Cloned ' + cast(@Count as varchar(10)))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Deal
            (DealName)
            SELECT @DealName + ' Cloned ' + cast(@Count as varchar(10))
                FROM Deal
                WHERE DealID = @DealId
            SET @NewDealId = @@IDENTITY
        SET @NameInvalid = 'false'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @NameInvalid = 'true'
        SET @Count = @Count + 1
    END
END
```

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" with this approach, but it's a bit shortsighted. The count of records does not always provide a unique suffix which is why you have to loop. This strategy opens a huge race condition where another invocation can insert the DealName between your existence check and the insert. Its procedural, error prone, and slow. Using an ancillary table (or steoleary's solution) as I suggested protects against these shortcomings, but it may be overkill for your requirements. More robust, but overkill.

Comment: Yeah in the end it was overkill as there is only 1 or 2 people using the system and this piece of code is called very rarely indeed. Unfortunately I didn't have the time to get your answer nto a SQL stored proc that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

So from my understanding of your problem, here's how I would approach it:

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[deal]
(
[dealName] varchar(100),
[resourceCount] int
)
```

Then create a unique index on the dealName column:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UQ_DealName] ON [dbo].[deal]
(
[dealName] ASC
)
```

Once you have the unique index, you can then just handle any exceptions such as a unique constraint violation (error 2601) directly in T-SQL using try/catch

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @dealName VARCHAR(100) = 'deal'
DECLARE @resourceCount INT = 8
DECLARE @count INT

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO dbo.deal (dealName,resourceCount)
    VALUES (@dealName, @resourceCount)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@ERROR = 2601
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(dealName) FROM dbo.deal WHERE resourceCount = @resourceCount)
        SET @resourceCount = (SELECT resourceCount FROM dbo.deal WHERE dealName = @dealName)
        SET @dealName = @dealName + ' Cloned ' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR(100))
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            INSERT INTO dbo.deal (dealName,resourceCount)
            VALUES (@dealName,@resourceCount)
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END
END CATCH
SELECT * FROM dbo.deal
```

You can easily put this code into a procedure, all it does is try and insert a deal name with the resource count, if the unique constraint is violated, it enters the catch block, appends the information that you want onto the deal name after finding the resource count of the original deal and then inserts these values.

It's not bulletproof by any means, but I find this technique really useful, not just for enforcing uniqueness, but you can use a similar way of handling exception numbers to deal with deadlocking, primary key violations and loads of other errors, all in T-SQL.

Comment: Ah the number at the end isn't related to the resource count... I just want the number at the end to increment until it finds a unique name

Comment: You could easily replace that bit with something else to count the number of deals with that name, my main aim was to show you how you can handle constraint violations totally within a stored procedure really.

Answer (score 1):

Ensuring the value is unique is easy: Create a [unique constraint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  If a unique value is inserted MSSQL will throw an exception and you can recover in your application.

Creating a unique name based on a counter (Proj1, Proj2, etc.) is a bit more involved.

Note, this is best mitigated in the web layer, where you can perform an existence check and inform the user prior to attempting the insert that the project name "is already in use." And, if this isnt an option, there are far simpler methods of ensuring uniqueness than enumerating a count as you've described. Appending a datetime or guid would make things relatively easy and would greatly (if not completely) avoid race conditions.

If you absolutely must implement in t-sql as requested then incorporating a *counter* column somewhere (ie, my "sequence" table below) should help minimize race conditions. I suspect even with the below example you might see some contention under high frequency calls.

```
--setup
/*
    --your existing table
    create table dbo.Project 
    (
        [ProjectName] varchar(100) primary key, 
        [ResourceCount] int
    );

    --a new table to transactionally constrain the increment
    create table dbo.ProjectNameSequence (ProjectName varchar(100) primary key, Seq int);

    --cleanup
    --drop table dbo.ProjectNameSequence
    --drop table dbo.Project

*/

declare @ProjectName varchar(100), @ResourceCount int;

set @ProjectName = 'Test Project XX';
set @ResourceCount = 9;


merge dbo.ProjectNameSequence [d]
using (values(@ProjectName)) [s] (ProjectName) on 
      d.ProjectName = s.ProjectName
when matched then update set Seq += 1
when not matched then insert values(@ProjectName, 1)
output  @ProjectName + case inserted.Seq when 1 then '' else cast(inserted.Seq as varchar) end, 
        @ResourceCount
into dbo.Project;  


select * from dbo.Project
```

Comment: Needs to be done in a stored proc only... I think I have it now using an IF EXISTS and a WHILE loop

Comment: @GavinMannion you can use the merge statement within the body of a stored procedure.